# How to source from stdout for both Linux and macOS?

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, bash, terminal

On Linux I can do:

```
source <(cat .env | grep ANDROID_GRADLE_TASK)
```

But on macOS, this doesn't do anything (no error, and no source)

1. What can I use for macOS?
2. Is there a command that works both on Linux (Debian/Ubuntu) and macOS?

Comment: macOS is (basically) BSD. You can lookup how to do this on BSD and it will probably work in Terminal on a Mac.

Comment: You asked a related question not too long ago. There is no `base64` call in there, so what’s this about `-di` or `--decode --input`? // You could also just use `eval`. The exact features depend on the shell in use, not the OS.

Comment: @KidACrimson That does not matter, it is the shell that makes the difference, which is `zsh` in this case

Comment: @DanielB you are right, I have updated the question, still I look for a way to source stdout on both linux and macos.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa your syntax works for me using the stock `zsh` in macOS Ventura 13.0. Is it possible your Mac doesn't have a `.env` file in the current working directory from which you ran that command, or that the `.env` file didn't contain a line containing `ANDROID_GRADLE_TASK`? I tested it with this one-liner: `echo -e 'echo "It worked!"\necho "...nope it failed!"' > tmp.txt && source <(cat tmp.txt | grep work)`, which should only echo "It worked!" if it worked correctly.

Comment: I am using /bin/bash within github action and no it does not work there.